# Gitlab misdetects binary file with text file and raises Internal Error (500 Whoops)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-8

#### What is Issue?

When I push a link of the commit which invlolves a binary file from Commits view of a project on Gitlab, I recieve an Internal error ,"500 Whoops, something went wrong on our end."

This issue also appears when creating Merge Request whose origin is the same commit above.
Production.log says,

---

```
Started GET "/TempTest/bsp/commit/3098a49f2fd1c77be0c383994aa6655f5d15ebf8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-30 16:17:15 +0900
Processing by Projects::CommitController#show as HTML
  Parameters:{"namespace_id"=>"TempTest", "project_id"=>"bsp", "id"=>"3098a49f2fd1c77be0c383994aa6655f5d15ebf8"}

Encoding::CompatibilityError (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT):
  app/views/projects/diffs/_file.html.haml:54:in `_app_views_projects_diffs__file_html_haml__1070266479743635718_49404820'
  app/views/projects/diffs/_diffs.html.haml:22:in `block in _app_views_projects_diffs__diffs_html_haml__2984561770205002953_48487320'
  app/views/projects/diffs/_diffs.html.haml:17:in `each_with_index'
  app/views/projects/diffs/_diffs.html.haml:17:in `_app_views_projects_diffs__diffs_html_haml__2984561770205002953_48487320'
  app/views/projects/commit/show.html.haml:12:in `_app_views_projects_commit_show_html_haml__3333221152053087461_45612480'
  app/controllers/projects/commit_controller.rb:30:in `show'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in `call'

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 210ms (Views: 8.7ms | ActiveRecord: 10.5ms)
```

---

Gtilab seems to misdetect binary file with text file.
So HTML formatting engine seems to meet an error.("Encoding::CompatibilityError")

It's ok for me that Gitlab sometimes misdetects binary file with text file, but problem is that Gitlab server stops the transaction by Internal Error when such a misdetects occurs.

Could anyone tell me how to continue server transaction even if such a misjudge occurs?
For example, I assume the following answer.

- e.g.1) Force to recognize a file to be a binary.
- e.g.2) Bypass a HTML transforming when such a error occurs.

---

#### What I tried to resolve.

I added the description '*.XXX binary' to .gitattribute to confirm whether I can let a certain file recognize that it was binary file for Gitlab forcibly.
The Git client recognized the file to be binary file, and the diff did not output a text. However, there was no effect in Gitlab even if I did push it.

#### versions info

- I faced this issue at first on Gitlab 8.6.2, but same issue occurs on 8.8.3.
- I use git-2.7.2

Thank you.